# React v18 and react-scripts v5 throwing a random error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

Here is a short background...

I migrated react from v17 to v18 successfully. App is running without errors.

After that I upgraded `react-scripts` from v4 to v5. There are no errors in the terminal but when i run the app, it's crashed (white screen). There is a strange error in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')`

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOmqI.jpg) is a screenshoot of the actual error:

This is the file where the above error is thrown:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import DashboardNavbar from '../DashboardNavbar';
import DashboardSidebar from '../DashboardSidebar';
import { StyledRoot, StyledContainer } from './DashboardLayout.styles';

const DashboardLayout = () => (
  <StyledRoot>
    <DashboardNavbar />
    <DashboardSidebar />
    <StyledContainer>
      <Outlet />
    </StyledContainer>
  </StyledRoot>
);

export default DashboardLayout;
```

Dependencies from package.json

```
{
 ...
 "react": "^18.2.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
 "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
 "typescript": "^4.8.4",
 ...
}
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Probably you forgot to pass prop to one of your child. Can you add child component's code?

Comment: Nope, none of them have props :/